# Accessing MainViewModel from another viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've a question on VM communication.

Here's my code in C#/WPF app.On my MainWindow.xam,I've a button.
On click of this button,
I need to access and modify the ProductList collection from within another ViewModel.
How do I achieve this please?

```
public List<ProductInfo> ProductList { get; private set; }

private MainWindow m_mvWindow = null;

public MainWindowViewModel(MainWindow window)
{
    this.m_mvWindow = window;
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(this); 
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an MVVM framework? I use MVVM Light and for such a problem I'd use the Messenger class (implementation of a Mediator pattern). The "other" VM would subscribe to a message and the MainViewModel would (in the command handling the button click) send the message.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If your `MainWindow` has a button, that button should trigger an `ICommand` from your `MainWindowViewModel` and that one would modify the data, probably through a service. If the data is shown in another view, too, then that view and the `MainWindow` should get their data from a common source, and that source should notify them of updates. _You really don't need to pass view models or commands to other view model or commands, they're there for the view._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to expose your other VM as a property of `MainWindowViewModel`, pass the child VM a reference to the ProductList collection and have an ICommand on the child VM which is bound to the button in your XAML and which handles the collection modifications.

Something like this:

Main VM

```
public class MainViewModel
{
   <!-- Your stuff ->
   public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel
   {
      if(_childViewModel == null)
      { 
         _childViewModel = new ChildViewModel(ProductList)
      }
      return _childViewModel;         
   }
}
```

Child VM

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
   private List<ProductInfo> _products;

   public DelegateCommand ClearCollection {get; set;}

   public ChildViewModel(List<ProductInfo> products)
   { 
      _products = products;
      ClearCollection = new DelegateCommand(OnClearCollection);
   }

   private void OnClearCollection()
   {
      _products.Clear();
   }
}
```

And in the xaml...

```
<Button Command={Binding ChildViewModel.ClearCommand} Content="..." />
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (I am very new to WPF) but this seems like an idea that would have limited implementation. I have an app I'm building and it has 15 views that would need to be coupled to the MainWindowViewModel. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: There's no intrinsic need to expose the ChildViewModel property. You can have a MainViewModel.ClearCommand which marshals the call through to the ChildViewModel itself. @Jay In your case I would look into Prisms EventAggregator for a fully decoupled method more suitable for multiple viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these ways:

1. Create an event in the other view model and handle it in the main view model. That would be the preferred way, since it does avoid coupling your child VM to the main VM, which is poor design.
2. Pass the collection to the child VM in a constructor. Try to avoid passing the full main VM, again to avoid coupling.